# Database doesn't get created

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a database like this :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydata.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
                    try
                    {
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vars (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, varname,varvalue);");
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO vars (varname,varvalue) VALUES (\"user\",\"" + username + "\");");
                    Log.w("Test", "Am executat sql");

                    }
                    catch (SQLiteException e)
                    {
                        Log.w("Exceptie", "Acum or niciodata");
                    }
```

When i restart my program and i want to open it like this :

```
  SQLiteDatabase objDb = null;
        try
        {
            objDb =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("mydata.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            //addShortcut();//setShortCut(getApplicationContext(),"GpsRo");
            //setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Log.w("Exceptie", e.getMessage());
            showForm = true;
        }
```

I get an exception : unable to open database file...

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post the error in the logcat

Comment: Unable to opendatabase file that's the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is in the wrong place:
"mydata.db" means your Databasefile is in root: (Path: /mydata.db). Your App can't write in the root folder.
Try `context.getFilesDir() + "/mydata.db"` instead.
In one Command:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(context.getFilesDir()"/mydata.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table creation query doesn't look good. Do it as below:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vars
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
varname TEXT,
varvalue TEXT);"
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see you are inserting data For varName and varValues not for id.Here id is a primary key ( that means it cannot be null and duplicate).So you must enter value for that you cannot left it blank and also you can go for AUTOINCREMENT.

Try something like this :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vars (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ASC, varname,varvalue);");
```

Comment: i don't get any exception in the sql sintax

Comment: Did you try it.Try it first please.

Answer (score 0):

to open your data base you need to declare something like this:

```
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private final Context mCtx;

mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

to make your Database writable

My suggestion is to go through  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

to learn more about SQLiteDataBases, there you will find a class called notesDbAdapter that you can use as a base, there you'll find a open() class that open the Data Base.

in other case to use the method openDataBase() you need to find the path of your DB on the device, and actualize  mydata.db to the full path of the DB.